# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'shape'Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to read my folder as a test data set folder. But I am very troubled by this problem.
My environment is python3.6+cuda9+pytorch1.4.0.

**code:**

```
# read images
# --------------------------------
test_results_ave = OrderedDict()
test_results_ave['psnr_sf_k'] = []

for sf in test_sf:
    for k_index in range(kernels.shape[1]):
        test_results = OrderedDict()
        test_results['psnr'] = []
        kernel = kernels[0, k_index].astype(np.float64)
```

**error：**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\USRNet-master\USRNet-master\main_test_table1.py", line 225, in <module>

    main()

  File "E:\USRNet-master\USRNet-master\main_test_table1.py", line 143, in main

    for k_index in range(kernels.shape[1]):

**AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'shape'**
```

Comment: Where's the `kernels`!!!!

Comment: @huangdali `kernels` is a `dict` while it should be `torch.Tensor`. Please post where `kernels` are defined.